# Drop Procedure - ORA-00933 - SQL command not properly ended

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to drop procedures in a database on click in C#.

Sql File: EXP_DROP_PROCEDURES.sql

```
drop procedure EXP_NAMES;
drop procedure EXP_TYPS;
drop procedure EXP_CARS;
drop procedure EXP_SHIPS;
```

Code C#:

```
            try
            {
                // Geht die SQL Skript in Basei
                var statement = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\" + "sql" + "\\" + "EXP_DROP_PROCEDURES.sql");
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(statement, oraCon))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }                  
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

I tried commit; at the end of EXP_DROP_PROCEDURES.sql and either without semicolons. Both did not work. It always brings me the exception ORA-00933 - SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: Most probably you'll have to execute the statement one by one in a loop or make it one PL/SQL block with `execute immediate`...

Comment: Did you try to remove just the last semicolon and let the other stay?

Comment: @Steve In Oracle, one command can only contain one statement.

Comment: OK, just thought that semicolons should go only between commands. But pretty inconvenient if you ask me.

Comment: @Steve It prevents many SQL injection vulnerabilities and you can wrap multiple statements in a PL/SQL block and pass that as a single command so the "inconvenience" as you put it is minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, one command can only contain one statement.

You either need to:

- read each line from the file and run those as separate commands (without the trailing semi-colon); or
- wrap the SQL statements in a PL/SQL anonymous block (and use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` since you cannot use `DROP` statements directly in PL/SQL):

  ```sql
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP PROCEDURE EXP_NAMES';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP PROCEDURE EXP_TYPS';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP PROCEDURE EXP_CARS';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP PROCEDURE EXP_SHIPS';
  END;
  ```

Comment: learned something again, thank you very much! ^^